# simpletransforers use_cuda=True not working

Tags: python, simpletransformers

wanted to try CUDA (I have an RTX 3070 TI) on my Windows setup, using this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn import preprocessing 

# Read data from JSON 
df = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\NLP and Computer Vision\Coding\News_Category_Dataset_v3.json", orient="records", lines=True)

print(df[df["headline"].isna() | df["short_description"].isna()])
print(df.head())


data = pd.DataFrame() 
data["text"] = df.headline + " " + df.short_description 
data["labels"] = df.category
 
labels = list(data["labels"].unique()) 

# Convert labels to numerical values 
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
le.fit(labels)
data["labels"] = le.transform(data["labels"])

train_df, eval_df = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2) 

# Create a classification model 
model = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-uncased', num_labels=len(labels), use_cuda=False) 

# Train the model 
model.train_model(train_df)
 
# Evaluate the model 
result, model_outputs, predictions = model.eval_model(eval_df)
```

It is running when I set use_cuda=False, when I enable it with True it's not working.

I installed the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit for Windows and on Anaconda. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what went wrong with the environment, but that was the issue.

I solved it using this env setup as yaml file:

```
name: nlp
channels:
  - pytorch
  - intel
  - nvidia
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - alabaster=0.7.12=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - anyio=3.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi=21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - arrow=1.2.3=py310haa95532_1
  - astroid=2.14.2=py310haa95532_0
  - asttokens=2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - atomicwrites=1.4.0=py_0
  - attrs=22.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - autopep8=1.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - babel=2.11.0=py310haa95532_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bcrypt=3.2.0=py310h2bbff1b_1
  - beautifulsoup4=4.12.2=py310haa95532_0
  - binaryornot=0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - black=23.3.0=py310haa95532_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h9128911_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h2bbff1b_1002
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2022.12.7=h5b45459_0
  - certifi=2022.12.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310h2bbff1b_3
  - chardet=4.0.0=py310haa95532_1003
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - click=8.0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - cloudpickle=2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=py310haa95532_0
  - comm=0.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - cookiecutter=1.7.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - cryptography=39.0.1=py310h21b164f_0
  - cuda-cccl=12.1.109=0
  - cuda-cudart=11.7.99=0
  - cuda-cudart-dev=11.7.99=0
  - cuda-cupti=11.7.101=0
  - cuda-libraries=11.7.1=0
  - cuda-libraries-dev=11.7.1=0
  - cuda-nvrtc=11.7.99=0
  - cuda-nvrtc-dev=11.7.99=0
  - cuda-nvtx=11.7.91=0
  - cuda-runtime=11.7.1=0
  - debugpy=1.5.1=py310hd77b12b_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - diff-match-patch=20200713=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - dill=0.3.6=py310haa95532_0
  - docstring-to-markdown=0.11=py310haa95532_0
  - docutils=0.18.1=py310haa95532_3
  - entrypoints=0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - executing=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - filelock=3.9.0=py310haa95532_0
  - flake8=6.0.0=py310haa95532_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=ha860e81_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h8cc25b3_3
  - glib=2.69.1=h5dc1a3c_2
  - gst-plugins-base=1.18.5=h9e645db_0
  - gstreamer=1.18.5=hd78058f_0
  - icc_rt=2022.1.0=h6049295_2
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - idna=3.4=py310haa95532_0
  - imagesize=1.4.1=py310haa95532_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.0.0=py310haa95532_0
  - importlib_metadata=6.0.0=hd3eb1b0_0
  - inflection=0.5.1=py310haa95532_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=haa95532_3556
  - intervaltree=3.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ipykernel=6.19.2=py310h9909e9c_0
  - ipython=8.12.0=py310haa95532_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - ipywidgets=8.0.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - isort=5.9.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jaraco.classes=3.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=py310haa95532_1
  - jellyfish=0.9.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - jinja2-time=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - joblib=1.2.0=pyh3f38642_0
  - jpeg=9e=h2bbff1b_1
  - jsonschema=4.17.3=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_client=8.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_core=5.3.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_server=1.23.4=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - keyring=23.13.1=py310haa95532_0
  - krb5=1.19.4=h5b6d351_0
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.6.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - lerc=3.0=hd77b12b_0
  - libclang=14.0.6=default_hb5a9fac_1
  - libclang13=14.0.6=default_h8e68704_1
  - libcublas=11.10.3.66=0
  - libcublas-dev=11.10.3.66=0
  - libcufft=10.7.2.124=0
  - libcufft-dev=10.7.2.124=0
  - libcurand=10.3.2.106=0
  - libcurand-dev=10.3.2.106=0
  - libcusolver=11.4.0.1=0
  - libcusolver-dev=11.4.0.1=0
  - libcusparse=11.7.4.91=0
  - libcusparse-dev=11.7.4.91=0
  - libdeflate=1.17=h2bbff1b_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=hd77b12b_6
  - libiconv=1.16=h2bbff1b_2
  - libnpp=11.7.4.75=0
  - libnpp-dev=11.7.4.75=0
  - libnvjpeg=11.8.0.2=0
  - libnvjpeg-dev=11.8.0.2=0
  - libogg=1.3.5=h2bbff1b_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h8cc25b3_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3=h6c2663c_0
  - libtiff=4.5.0=h6c2663c_2
  - libuv=1.44.2=h2bbff1b_0
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=he774522_0
  - libwebp=1.2.4=hbc33d0d_1
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h2bbff1b_1
  - libxml2=2.10.3=h0ad7f3c_0
  - libxslt=1.1.37=h2bbff1b_0
  - lxml=4.9.2=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=py310haa95532_0
  - mccabe=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py310h2bbff1b_1000
  - mkl=2021.4.0=haa95532_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310ha0764ea_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - more-itertools=8.12.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - mpmath=1.2.1=py310haa95532_0
  - mypy_extensions=0.4.3=py310haa95532_1
  - nbclassic=0.5.5=py310haa95532_0
  - nbclient=0.5.13=py310haa95532_0
  - nbconvert=6.5.4=py310haa95532_0
  - nbformat=5.7.0=py310haa95532_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.6=py310haa95532_0
  - networkx=2.8.4=py310haa95532_1
  - notebook=6.5.4=py310haa95532_0
  - notebook-shim=0.2.2=py310haa95532_0
  - numexpr=2.8.4=py310hd213c9f_0
  - numpy=1.24.3=py310hdc03b94_0
  - numpy-base=1.24.3=py310h3caf3d7_0
  - numpydoc=1.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - openssl=1.1.1t=h2bbff1b_0
  - packaging=23.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pandas=1.5.3=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - paramiko=2.8.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pathspec=0.10.3=py310haa95532_0
  - pcre=8.45=hd77b12b_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pillow=9.4.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pip=23.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - platformdirs=2.5.2=py310haa95532_0
  - pluggy=1.0.0=py310haa95532_1
  - ply=3.11=py310haa95532_0
  - pooch=1.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - poyo=0.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - prometheus_client=0.14.1=py310haa95532_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.36=py310haa95532_0
  - psutil=5.9.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pycodestyle=2.10.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pydocstyle=6.3.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pyflakes=3.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - pylint=2.16.2=py310haa95532_0
  - pyls-spyder=0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pynacl=1.5.0=py310h8cc25b3_0
  - pyopenssl=23.0.0=py310haa95532_0
  - pyqt=5.15.7=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyqtwebengine=5.15.7=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyrsistent=0.18.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - python=3.10.11=h966fe2a_2
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=py310haa95532_0
  - python-lsp-black=1.2.1=py310haa95532_0
  - python-lsp-jsonrpc=1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-lsp-server=1.7.2=py310haa95532_0
  - python-slugify=5.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pytoolconfig=1.2.5=py310haa95532_1
  - pytorch=2.0.0=py3.10_cuda11.7_cudnn8_0
  - pytorch-cuda=11.7=h16d0643_3
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0=cuda
  - pytz=2022.7=py310haa95532_0
  - pywin32=305=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pywin32-ctypes=0.2.0=py310haa95532_1000
  - pywinpty=2.0.10=py310h5da7b33_0
  - pyyaml=6.0=py310h2bbff1b_1
  - pyzmq=25.0.2=py310hd77b12b_0
  - qdarkstyle=3.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - qt-main=5.15.2=he8e5bd7_8
  - qt-webengine=5.15.9=hb9a9bb5_5
  - qtconsole=5.4.2=py310haa95532_0
  - qtpy=2.2.0=py310haa95532_0
  - qtwebkit=5.212=h2bbfb41_5
  - requests=2.29.0=py310haa95532_0
  - rope=1.7.0=py310haa95532_0
  - rtree=1.0.1=py310h2eaa2aa_0
  - scikit-learn=1.2.1=py310hd77b12b_0
  - scipy=1.10.1=py310hb9afe5d_0
  - send2trash=1.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - setuptools=66.0.0=py310haa95532_0
  - sip=6.6.2=py310hd77b12b_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py310haa95532_1
  - snowballstemmer=2.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - soupsieve=2.4=py310haa95532_0
  - sphinx=5.0.2=py310haa95532_0
  - sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - spyder=5.4.3=py310haa95532_1
  - spyder-kernels=2.4.3=py310haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h2bbff1b_0
  - stack_data=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sympy=1.11.1=py310haa95532_0
  - terminado=0.17.1=py310haa95532_0
  - text-unidecode=1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - textdistance=4.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - three-merge=0.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h2bbff1b_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tomlkit=0.11.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tornado=6.2=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - traitlets=5.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - typing-extensions=4.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - typing_extensions=4.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - ujson=5.4.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - unidecode=1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - urllib3=1.26.15=py310haa95532_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - watchdog=2.1.6=py310haa95532_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py310haa95532_1
  - websocket-client=0.58.0=py310haa95532_4
  - whatthepatch=1.0.2=py310haa95532_0
  - wheel=0.38.4=py310haa95532_0
  - widgetsnbextension=4.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - wrapt=1.14.1=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - xz=5.2.10=h8cc25b3_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=he774522_0
  - yapf=0.31.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - zeromq=4.3.4=hd77b12b_0
  - zipp=3.11.0=py310haa95532_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h8cc25b3_0
  - zstd=1.5.5=hd43e919_0
  - pip:
      - absl-py==1.4.0
      - aiohttp==3.8.4
      - aiosignal==1.3.1
      - altair==4.2.2
      - async-timeout==4.0.2
      - blinker==1.6.2
      - cachetools==5.3.0
      - datasets==2.12.0
      - docker-pycreds==0.4.0
      - frozenlist==1.3.3
      - fsspec==2023.4.0
      - gitdb==4.0.10
      - gitpython==3.1.31
      - google-auth==2.17.3
      - google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
      - grpcio==1.54.0
      - huggingface-hub==0.14.1
      - markdown==3.4.3
      - markdown-it-py==2.2.0
      - mdurl==0.1.2
      - multidict==6.0.4
      - multiprocess==0.70.14
      - oauthlib==3.2.2
      - pathtools==0.1.2
      - protobuf==3.20.3
      - pyarrow==11.0.0
      - pyasn1==0.5.0
      - pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
      - pydeck==0.8.1b0
      - pygments==2.15.1
      - pylint-venv==2.3.0
      - pympler==1.0.1
      - pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
      - qstylizer==0.2.2
      - qtawesome==1.2.2
      - regex==2023.3.23
      - requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
      - responses==0.18.0
      - rich==13.3.5
      - rsa==4.9
      - sentencepiece==0.1.98
      - sentry-sdk==1.21.1
      - seqeval==1.2.2
      - setproctitle==1.3.2
      - simpletransformers==0.63.11
      - smmap==5.0.0
      - streamlit==1.22.0
      - tenacity==8.2.2
      - tensorboard==2.12.2
      - tensorboard-data-server==0.7.0
      - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
      - tokenizers==0.13.3
      - toolz==0.12.0
      - torchaudio==2.0.0
      - torchvision==0.15.0
      - tqdm==4.65.0
      - transformers==4.28.1
      - tzdata==2023.3
      - tzlocal==4.3
      - validators==0.20.0
      - wandb==0.15.0
      - werkzeug==2.3.2
      - xxhash==3.2.0
      - yarl==1.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that your system has a compatible GPU and that the necessary drivers are installed.
then when you are using use_cuda=True, send the 'fp16' parameter to enable mixed-precision training, which can improve training speed and memory usage and the device parameter to specify which GPU to use :

```
model = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-uncased', num_labels=len(labels), use_cuda=True, args={'fp16': True, 'device': 'cuda:0'})
```

you can set device='cuda:0' to use the first GPU or device='cuda:1' to use the second GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, you suggestion definitely helped boosting the calculations!